# Expose User controls Inner controls to Visual Studio Properties window at design time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I have a user control which acts as a button. I want the users of this button to be able to set the text in the inner label of the control via the Properties window in Visual Studio at design time, when they place this control onto a form or whatever. Specifically I mean I want them to be able to put the control on a form, click said control, and then in the properties window see something like Text and be able to provide the text for the label. Im not really sure what to search for because its sort of a complicated question, hopefully one with a simple answer. Does anyone know what I would need to add to my code or XAML to accomplish this?

Here is the XAML for completeness: Note the content attribute of the label.

```
<UserControl x:Class="CartControllerForms.UserControls.TileButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="81" Width="364">
    <Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="8,8,8,8">
        <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop x:Name="Stop1" Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop x:Name="Stop2" Color="#FF666262" Offset="0.843"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <Grid Margin="9" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="61" Width="344">
        <Label x:Name="TextLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,16,10,19" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Width="324" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Verdana" 
                   FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFB8BCBD" Content="I want this exposed"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseEnter">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Stop2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="Blue" Duration="0" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseLeave">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Stop2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="#FF666262" Duration="0" />
                </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </UserControl.Triggers>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a property available via XAML (or the designer for that matter) you need to expose it as a `DependencyProperty`. The easiest way to make one is via the `propdp` snippet.

Heres what one looks like:

```
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Value.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty=
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyButton), new PropertyMetadata("", HandleValueChange));
```

The last argument on the metadata is the change event handler, and is optional. In your control's `Loaded` event you would set the label text to `Text`. If you want to support binding updates, you would include the change event handler and update there.

Comment: This is beautiful! Thank you very much Bradley, worked first time around with no headaches. Ill accept the answer as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: @MarkW Glad to help! Make sure to remember the snippet, you will use this code a *lot*.